# Pull data from Postgres, and in show it in a template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django, all I am trying to do is pull a table from postgres database and post it in html, when I do a runserver, it has to display all the records from the table, since I am testing I only used 4 columns in the Html.py

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

#class Shop(models.Model):
class Anchor(models.Model):

    # site_cd_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # site_lat = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    # site_long = models.FloatField(max_length=100)


    record_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
    unique_system_identifier = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=0, null=False)
    uls_file_number=models.CharField(max_length=14,null=True)
    ebf_number=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    call_sign=models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    partition_area_idnumeric=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0,max_digits=9, null=True)
    lower_frequency=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8,max_digits=16, null=True)
    upper_frequency=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8,max_digits=16, null=True)
    def_und_indicator=models.CharField(max_length=1,null=True)
    defined_partition_area=models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True)


class Meta:
    db_table = 'mf'

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %d %s %s %s %d %d %d  %s %s" %(self.record_type,self.unique_system_identifier,self.uls_file_number,self.ebf_number,self.call_sign,
        self.partition_area_idnumeric,self.lower_frequency,self.upper_frequency,self.def_und_indicator,self.defined_partition_area)
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from .models import Anchor
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.




def index(request):
    model= Anchor
    context_object_name= "Anchors"
    data = Anchor.objects.all()
    # record_type1 = queryset.record_type
    template_name="Anchors/index.html"
    context = {
        'context_object_name': context_object_name,
           }
    # html = "<html><body>Room 1 will be used by %s</body></html>" % record_type1
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>sample print of data</h1>
    <p>
        {% for record in data %}
            {{ data.unique_system_identifier}}
            {{ data.uls_file_number }}
            {{ data.lower_frequency }}
            {{ data.upper_frequency }}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>

<!--     <a href="/">logout</a>
 --></body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from anchors import views

urlpatterns = [path("", views.index,name="index"), path("admin/", admin.site.urls)]
```

I am not able to understand where am i doing wrong

Comment: Split it up in several small problems, look where it goes wrong and if you can't find it focus on the small problem and post it here. Nobody will read your entire program.

Comment: `for >>>record<< in ...` vs `{{ >>>data<<<.* }}`

Comment: @ Elmex80s okay, problem is the data is not being poplated on html, i can only see the header (sample print of data) it doesnt throw any error.

Comment: @ Ivan Starostin -  Just tried that but no diference, also will update the same in the question

Answer (score 1):

There are still some problems with your code, both in the view and the template.

```
def index(request):
    data = Anchor.objects.all()
    template_name="Anchors/index.html"
    context = {
        'data': data
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

...

```
    {% for record in data %}
        {{ record.unique_system_identifier}}
        {{ record.uls_file_number }}
        {{ record.lower_frequency }}
        {{ record.upper_frequency }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Just tried this, its not printing any data other than the header "sample print of data"